# kernel crash after opening R in jupyter

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I start using `R` in `jupyter`, and I tried to install the library `tidyverse` from anaconda prompt. since then whene ever I open `R` in `jupyter` the kernel crash. but python's kernel works.

Comment: You could have pasted the message text only, usually text is preferred here in SO, specially if it involves code, or message errors.

Comment: oh, and welcome to SO.